# interior product equality

Tags: inner-products, differential-forms

im having a hard time proving that for 2 differential forms $\omega\in \Omega^m(V)$ and $\eta \in \Omega^n(V)$ and a smooth vector field $v$ on $V$, that we have $j_v(\omega \wedge \eta)= j_v\omega\wedge \eta +(-1)^m\omega \wedge j_v\eta$.  This looks extremely similar to this equation $d(\omega \wedge \eta)=d\omega \wedge \eta +(-1)^m\omega \wedge d\eta$, which i already proved. Where exactly is the connection between those two, and what exactly do i need to modify in my prove for the second equality to obtain the first one? ( Also im sorry for not making it more readable, because i dont know how to make new lines). Thanks in advance !

Comment: What in the world is $j_v$? I guess everyone except me knows it is the interior product $\iota_v$??

Comment: yeah my title contained that the interior product was meant, should have specified it in the question too

Comment: Oh, I see, it's in the title. MORE argument to incorporate the title into the text of the question, which we ask people to do. I just noticed this as you were responding to me. If you had used the standard notion $\iota_v$, of course, I would have understood.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to prove it: Let $\alpha^1,\dots,\alpha^k\in\Omega^1(V)$ be one-forms. Then we have $$\iota_v(\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^k)=\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i+1}\alpha^i(v)\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\alpha^i}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^k$$
where the hat over $\alpha^i$ means that this term is omitted. This is just the Leibniz expansion of determinants in the following formula $$(\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^k)(v_1,\dots,v_k)=\det(\alpha^i(v_j))_{ij}$$
By linearity of $\iota_v$ we are reduced to show that the claim holds in the case where $\omega,\eta$ are of the form \begin{align*}
\omega&=\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^m\\
\eta&=\beta^1\wedge\dots\wedge\beta^n
\end{align*}
for one-forms $\alpha^i,\beta^j$. So we get: \begin{align*}
\iota_v(\omega\wedge\eta)&=\iota_v(\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^m\wedge\beta^1\wedge\dots\wedge\beta^n)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m(-1)^{i+1}\alpha^i(v)\alpha^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\alpha^i}\wedge\dots\wedge\alpha^m\wedge\beta^1\wedge\dots\wedge\beta^n\\&\hspace{0.7cm}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j+1+m}\beta^i(v)\alpha^1\wedge\dots\alpha^n\wedge\beta ^1\wedge\dots\wedge\widehat{\beta ^j}\wedge\dots\wedge\beta ^m\\
&=\iota_v(\omega)\wedge\eta+(-1)^m\omega\wedge\iota_v(\eta)
\end{align*}

Comment: yeah that makes sense, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The connection lies in the [Lie derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative).
For all vector fields $X$, the Lie derivative, as the name suggests, is an operator on forms $\mathcal L_X : \Omega^k(M)\to\Omega^k(M)$ defined as
$$\mathcal L_X(\alpha):=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0}(\varphi^{(X)*}_t \alpha),$$
where $\varphi^{(X)}_t$ is the flux associated to $X$. Here, the definition is unimportant: what matters is that
$\mathcal L_X$ is a differential operator, and as such it satisfies the product rule
$$
\mathcal{L}_{X}(\omega \wedge \eta)=\left(\mathcal{L}_{X} \omega\right) \wedge \eta+\omega \wedge\left(\mathcal{L}_{X} \eta\right); \tag1
$$
also, Cartan's "magic" formula connects it with $j_X$ and $d$ in an interesting way:
$$\mathcal L_X\omega = j_X(d\omega)+d(j_X\omega). \tag2$$
This entails
$$\begin{split}
\mathcal L_X(\omega \wedge \eta)&=j_Xd(\omega\wedge\eta)+dj_X(\omega\wedge \eta) \\
(\mathcal L_X \omega)\wedge \eta + \omega\wedge(\mathcal L_X\eta)&=j_X((d\omega)\wedge \eta)+ (-1)^mj_X(\omega\wedge(d\eta)) \\
&\quad+d((j_X\omega) \wedge \eta + (-1)^m \omega \wedge (j_X\eta)) \\
0 &= (-1)^{m+1}(d\omega)\wedge(j_X\eta) + (-1)^m(j_X\omega)\wedge(d\eta)\\
&\quad+(-1)^{m}(d\omega)\wedge(j_X\eta) + (-1)^{m-1}(j_X\omega)\wedge(d\eta) \\
0&=0,
\end{split}$$
by applying the magic formula on the LHS as well, and the graded product rules you stated on the RHS (twice), thus proving their consistency (at least if you trust $(1)$ and $(2)$!).

Comment: I've read a little into Lie dervivatives and this seems to answer a majority of my questions and problems i had, thanks for this :)

Comment: @bsvgu you’re welcome!